# AngularJS - Error controller is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is a very common problem apparently when declaring multiple controllers but every fix on this forum that I tried to follow or somewhere else, didn't seem to work (probably am missing something).

I have app.js file and 3 separate controller files and a services file.

I used one of the controllers and everything worked fine. Now I am trying to redirect to another view which handled by ProfileManagement controller, but it is showing the error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ProfileManagementController' is not a
>   function, got undefined

This is what I have in the beginning of each controller file and also app.js...

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services']);

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {...
```

and in app.js, I am using this route before the error shows:

```
.state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'tab-home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
        controller: 'ProfileManagementController'
      }
    }
  })
```

My controllers are here...

UserAccessController:

```
app.controller('UserAccessController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$q', '$rootScope', 'CreateUserService', 'UserObjectService', function($scope, $http, $state, $q, $rootScope, CreateUserService, UserObjectService){
```

and ProfileManagementController:

```
app.controller('ProfileManagementController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

}]);
```

Also with tabs project template of ionic framework, I got the file controller.js by default where I commented all controllers but left the first line:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', []);

//.controller('ProfileController', function($scope) {})
//
//.controller('OrdersController', function($scope) {
//  
//})
//
//.controller('MoreOptionsController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
//  
//})
//
//.controller('ConnectionsController', function($scope) {
//  
//});
```

What am I doing wrong here that leads to the error message? (the view actually associated with the route tabs.home actually loads but the console shows the error.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you load the controller script to the html. I mean `<script ...`?

Comment: you mean the index.html or the sub-views?

Comment: Somewhere. `index.html` is better

Comment: yes I am updating the post now to show the index.html

Comment: oops forgot to add     <script src="js/ProfileManagementController.js"></script>
This actually fixed it. To close the question, if you want to post your recommendation and then I can select it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to add the script tag to define your controller within the html.

for example:

```
<script src="yourController.js"></script>
```